# What is Leibush Up To

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The verse in Proverbs (19:21) states regarding Leibush:

> רבות מחשבות בלביש ועצת ה' היא תקום

"Many thoughts are in Leibush, but God's plan will prevail".

Who is Leibush and what is he planning?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

Leibush in this verse refers to [Rabbeinu Meir Leibush-Malbim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim), who was known for his battles against the Maskilim. However, God's plan is that the Maskilim prevail, as Scripture tells us:

> והמשכילים--יזהירו, כזוהר הרקיע; ומצדיקי, הרבים, ככוכבים, לעולם ועד.
>   Daniel 12:3

Comment: This feels like a little much, even for Purim Torah. May delete it later.

Comment: (re your comment) Oh, please don't! It's brilliant!

Comment: Just a little close to home, because I have some maskilish leanings myself. I even minored in Wissenschaft des Judentums in college.